# SQL Match and update [names to IDs]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `order_table` and a `user_table`.

When the database was designed (in 1998), the `order_table` was saving the `full_name` of users only (not the `UserID`).

Now, I would like to add a column `UserID` to the `order_table` and match and update (by a unique column  ei. `email`) in `user_table`.

Is there another way to resolve this issue?

If you can, could you describe how you'd approach this issue using SQL?

This is how the `order_table` looks:

```
+-------+--------------+
| Order | UserFullName |
+-------+--------------+
| 534   | John doe     |
| 5453  | John doe1    |
| 653   | David        |
| 64432 | Jane doe     |
+-------+--------------+
```

This is how the users' table looks

```
+----+-----------+------------------+
| Id | User      | Email            |
+----+-----------+------------------+
| 1  | John doe  | jd@gmail.com     |
| 2  | John doe1 | jd12@gmail.com   |
| 3  | David     | davidd@yahoo.com |
| 4  | jane doe  | msjane@oal.com   |
+----+-----------+------------------+
```

The final desired result should be:

```
+-------+--------------+--------------------------------+
| Order | UserFullName | UserID (matched from user_tbl) |
+-------+--------------+--------------------------------+
| 534   | John doe     | 1                              |
| 653   | David        | 3                              |
| 5453  | John doe1    | 2                              |
| 64432 | Jane doe     | 4                              |
+-------+--------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm providing the requested samples

Comment: What common keys are there between the two tables? E.g. do you have the [email] column in both [order_table] and [user_table]?

Comment: @JamesMc the only common record is the name -- all the names are unique

Comment: Take a backup first of all the involved tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sql, it assumes you have email fields on both tables.

```
alter table order_table add userid int

update o set userid = u.userid from order_table o inner join user_table u on o.email = u.email
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that full names are unique in Order_table, You can add UserId to User_Table and Order_Table as given below.

```sql
-- step no. 1 : Adding UserId column to user_table, Order_Table
ALTER TABLE user_table
ADD COLUMN UserId INT

ALTER TABLE Order_table
ADD COLUMN UserId INT

-- Step No.2: Updating userId in user_table
;WITH CTE_Users AS
(
select Email,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Email) as rnk
FROM user_table)
UPDATE u
SET UserId = c.rnk
FROM user_table as u
inner join cte_users as c
On c.Email = u.Email

-- Step No.3: Updating userId in Order_table
UPDATE o
SET o.UserId = u.UserId
FROM Order_table as o
INNER JOIN user_Table as u
ON u.UserFullName = o.UserFullName

--Step No.4: Final result can be simply queried from Order_Table itself, as it has userid
SELECT Order,UserFullName, UserId
FROM Order_table
```